# Using self in init part of a class in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, neural-network, pytorch, self

Is there any difference between the following two codes related to initializing a class in Python?

```py
class summation: 
    def __init__(self, f, s): 
        self.first = f 
        self.second = s 
        self.summ = self.first + self.second
    .
    .
    .
```

```py
class summation: 
    def __init__(self, f, s): 
        self.first = f 
        self.second = s 
        self.summ = f + s
    .
    .
    .
```

If there exists any difference, what is that, and which code is preferable?

**Edit:** I am going to write an artificial neural network with Python (and Pytorch). In fact, the above two codes are just some examples. In the actual case, I have seen in various resources that when there exists `self.input = input` in the initialization of a class, in other parts it is used as `self.input`, not `input`.

**My questions:** What are the differences between these two approaches? Why is the use of `self.input` preferable, in my case?

**Example:** (from https://docs.dgl.ai/en/latest/tutorials/models/1_gnn/4_rgcn.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-models-1-gnn-4-rgcn-py)

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from dgl import DGLGraph
import dgl.function as fn
from functools import partial

class RGCNLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_feat, out_feat, num_rels, num_bases=-1, bias=None,
                 activation=None, is_input_layer=False):
        super(RGCNLayer, self).__init__()
        self.in_feat = in_feat
        self.out_feat = out_feat
        self.num_rels = num_rels
        self.num_bases = num_bases
        self.bias = bias
        self.activation = activation
        self.is_input_layer = is_input_layer

        # sanity check
        if self.num_bases <= 0 or self.num_bases > self.num_rels:
            self.num_bases = self.num_rels

        # weight bases in equation (3)
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(self.num_bases, self.in_feat,
                                                self.out_feat))
        if self.num_bases < self.num_rels:
            # linear combination coefficients in equation (3)
            self.w_comp = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(self.num_rels, self.num_bases))

        # add bias
        if self.bias:
            self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_feat))

        # init trainable parameters
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.weight,
                                gain=nn.init.calculate_gain('relu'))
        if self.num_bases < self.num_rels:
            nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.w_comp,
                                    gain=nn.init.calculate_gain('relu'))
        if self.bias:
            nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.bias,
                                    gain=nn.init.calculate_gain('relu'))

    def forward(self, g):
        if self.num_bases < self.num_rels:
            # generate all weights from bases (equation (3))
            weight = self.weight.view(self.in_feat, self.num_bases, self.out_feat)
            weight = torch.matmul(self.w_comp, weight).view(self.num_rels,
                                                        self.in_feat, self.out_feat)
        else:
            weight = self.weight

        if self.is_input_layer:
            def message_func(edges):
                # for input layer, matrix multiply can be converted to be
                # an embedding lookup using source node id
                embed = weight.view(-1, self.out_feat)
                index = edges.data['rel_type'] * self.in_feat + edges.src['id']
                return {'msg': embed[index] * edges.data['norm']}
        else:
            def message_func(edges):
                w = weight[edges.data['rel_type']]
                msg = torch.bmm(edges.src['h'].unsqueeze(1), w).squeeze()
                msg = msg * edges.data['norm']
                return {'msg': msg}

        def apply_func(nodes):
            h = nodes.data['h']
            if self.bias:
                h = h + self.bias
            if self.activation:
                h = self.activation(h)
            return {'h': h}

        g.update_all(message_func, fn.sum(msg='msg', out='h'), apply_func)
```

Comment: I would challenge either - if `self.first` or `self.second` is changed, `self.summ` goes out-of-date. Instead, it should be a *property* calculated on access. Given that `self.first` and `self.second` could *also* be properties, it's possible that the two versions would actually have different behaviour, so it's not a matter of preference so much which behaviour makes sense in your context.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your comment. Would you please give me an example in which the above two codes have different behaviors?

Comment: It *may* be different if `summation.first` and `summation.second` are *descriptors* (e.g. like `property`) because then `self.first` and `self.second` will call the descriptor's `__get__` method which can do anything arbitrarily.

Comment: @ZahraTaheri take a look at my edited answer. I hope it clarifies everything for you now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. there is no difference between these two approaches in your case with this level of information. but could they? **Yes**. they could. if they have some modifications in their *setters* or *getters*. later in my answer I'll show you how.

First of all, I prefer using this one:

```
class summation: 
    def __init__(self, f, s): 
        self.first = f 
        self.second = s 
    @property
    def summ(self):
        return self.first+self.second
```

the above implementation calculates the summation on demand. so when you change `self.first` or `self.second`, `summ` will be calculated automatically. you can access the sum as you did before.

```
s = summation(1,9)
print(s.summ)
# 10
s.first = 2
s.second = 3
print(s.summ)
# 5
```

### So, How could they be different?

let's implements them as follows. in *setters* I doubled the inputs to show you how setters can affect the results. it's just an imaginary example and is not exactly what you wrote.

```
class summation1: 
    def __init__(self, f, s): 
        self.first = f 
        self.second = s 
        self.summ = self.first + self.second

    @property
    def first(self):
      return self.__first

    @first.setter
    def first(self,f):
      self.__first = f*2

    @property
    def second(self):
      return self.__second

    @second.setter
    def second(self,s):
      self.__second = s*2


class summation2: 
    def __init__(self, f, s): 
        self.first = f 
        self.second = s 
        self.summ = f + s

    @property
    def first(self):
      return self.__first

    @first.setter
    def first(self,f):
      self.__first = f*2

    @property
    def second(self):
      return self.__second

    @second.setter
    def second(self,s):
      self.__second = s*2
```

now let's take a look at the outputs:

```
a = 3
b = 2
s1 = summation1(a,b)
s2 = summation2(a,b)

print(s1.summ)
# 10
print(s2.summ)
# 5
```

so, if you are not sure what to choose between those two, maybe the first approach is what you need.

Comment: There *can* be a difference - what if `self.first` and `self.second` are *also* properties?

Comment: @ZahraTaheri please add their codes to the question. if the getter parts of them do something, then may I need to change the answer.

Comment: @ZahraTaheri if you didn't change anything in `self.first` and `self.second` the result would be the same. by the way, whenever you are not sure what to choose between these two, the first approach (`self.first+self.second`) is **safer** to use always. but I highly recommend you to use the third one (my approach)

Comment: @MahradHanaforoosh Thanks a lot for your answer. I added some parts to my question.

Comment: @MahradHanaforoosh Thank you so much for your helpful answer.

Comment: @ZahraTaheri your welcome. I'm glad I helped.